# oncomplete not working in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, salesforce1-app

I am trying to build a visualforce page which can work in salesforce and also salesforce1. I am trying to redirect after the action is completed it work just fine when i try it from desktop but from my salesforce1 app it don't work. i found out the javascript function which i am trying to call on oncomplete is not even invocking this fuction. please help.

```
<apex:page id="idPage" docType="html-5.0" showHeader="{!!isSF1}" sidebar="{!!isSF1}" applyBodyTag="{!!isSF1}" applyHtmlTag="{!!isSF1}" standardStylesheets="{!!isSF1}" standardController="Lead" extensions="leadConvertController">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/canvas/sdk/js/publisher.js'></script>    
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap, '/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}"></apex:includeScript>
    <style>
    .ui-mobile{
        min-height:200px;
    }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function redirect(recordId) {
            //var url = "/{!Lead.Id}";
            system.log('Redirect: ' + recordId);
            if (typeof sforce !== 'undefined'){ 
                sforce.one.navigateToSObject(recordId); 
            } else { 
                //.top to deal with the fact that publisher actions in chatter feed are iframe 
                window.top.location.href= "/" + recordId; 
            } 


            //if ( (typeof sforce.one) !== "undefined" && sforce.one !== null ) {
            //    sforce.one.back(true);                
            //  //parent.frames.location.replace(url)
            //  //window.Location=url;
            //}
            //else {
            //    parent.frames.location.replace(url); 
            //  //sforce.one.back(true);
            //  //sforce.one.navigateToURL(url);
            //  //sforce.one.navigateToSObject(url,'detail');
            //}         
        }
       jQuery(document).ready(function($){
           //$('[class$=OutputTextClass]').attr("disabled",true);
           $('.OutputTextClass').attr("disabled",true);
       });
    </script>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap,'/css/bootstrap-namespaced.min.css')}"/>
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!isOnError}" id="idOPMessage">
        <apex:form id="idFormErrorMessage">
            <apex:outputLabel value="{!ErrorMessage}" escape="false"></apex:outputLabel><BR/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!Back}" rendered="{!ShowBack}" value="Back" onClick="redirect('{!Lead.Id}');"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!Ok}" rendered="{!ShowOk}" value="Ok" onClick="redirect('{!accountID.Id}');"/>
            <!--apex:commandButton action="{!Back}" value="Back" onClick="redirect();"/-->
        </apex:form>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!!isOnError}" id="idOPContent"> 
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!!isSF1}">
            <!-- Page section header -->
            <apex:sectionHeader title="Convert Lead" subtitle="{!Lead.name}"/>
            <!-- Visualforce Component with custom page header text -->
            <!--c:leadConvertPageHeaderTextComponent /-->
            <!-- This form tag must include any fields or buttons used in the Lead Convert operation -->         
            <apex:form id="theForm" >
                <!-- This pageBlock component is a container that includes the visual elements of the Lead Convert page -->
                <!-- All custom Components should be included within this pageBlock unless you are using more advanced custom styling -->
                <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="pageBlock">        
                    <!-- This component is used to display error messages on the page -->                  
                    <apex:pageMessages />                  
                    <!-- This pageBlockButtons component is where you can add / remove custom buttons from the Lead Convert page -->           
                    <apex:pageBlockButtons >               
                        <apex:commandButton action="{!convertLead}" value="Convert"/>
                        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>                    
                    </apex:pageBlockButtons>                       

                    <apex:pageBlockSection id="pblockconvertLead" title="Convert Lead" collapsible="no" columns="1">

                        <!-- Leads Record Owner -->
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                            <apex:outputLabel value="Record Owner" for="recordOwner" />
                            <apex:inputField value="{!contactId.ownerID}" id="recordOwner" />
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                        <!-- Checkbox indicating whether to send an email to the owner -->    
                        <!--apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                            <apex:outputLabel value="Send Email to the Owner" for="sendOwnerEmail" />
                            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!sendOwnerEmail}" id="sendOwnerEmail" />
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem-->


                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="convertLeadAccountBlockSectionItem" >
                            <apex:outputLabel value="Account Name" for="accountId" />
                            <apex:outputField value="{!accountID.Name}" id="accountId" />
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                        <!-- Opportunity section -->
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="oppSection" >

                            <apex:outputPanel id="oppPanel" >
                                <apex:outputLabel value="Opportunity Name" for="opportunityName" />
                            </apex:outputPanel>


                            <apex:outputPanel id="opportunityPanel" layout="block">
                                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(doNotCreateOppty)}" styleClass="requiredInput" id="block">
                                <div class="requiredBlock"></div>

                                <!-- Opportunity Name -->
                                <apex:inputField required="false" 
                                    value="{!opportunityID.Name}" id="opportunityName"/>
                                </apex:outputPanel>

                                <!--  This is only shown if the Do Not Create Opportunity is true -->    
                                <apex:inputText disabled="true" rendered="{!doNotCreateOppty}"  value="{!opportunityID.Name}" id="opportunityNameDisabled"/>
                                <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="requiredInput">
                                <apex:outputPanel layout="block" />

                                <!-- Checkbox indicating whether to create an Opportunity -->
                                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!doNotCreateOppty}" id="doNotCreateOppty">
                                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" 

                                        rerender="opportunityPanel"
                                         />
                                </apex:inputCheckbox>
                                Do not create a new opportunity upon conversion.
                            </apex:outputPanel> 
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                        <!-- Converted Status -->
                        <!--apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                            <apex:outputLabel value="Converted Status" for="leadStatus" />
                            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block">
                                <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
                                <apex:selectList id="LeadStatusList" size="1" 
                                    value="{!LeadToConvert.Status}" multiselect="false" required="true">
                                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!LeadStatusOption}"/>
                                </apex:selectList> 
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem-->
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:form>       
        </apex:outputPanel>    
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!isSF1}" id="opSF1">
            <head>          
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
                <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
                <!-- jQuery Mobile -->
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
                <apex:stylesheet value="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
                <apex:includeScript value="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" />
                <apex:includeScript value="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js" />
                <!-- Salesforce1 -->
                <apex:includeScript value="/canvas/sdk/js/publisher.js" />                
            </head>


            <body>          
                <div data-role="page">
                    <!--h1>{!$ObjectType.Lead.Label}: <small>{!Lead.name}</small></h1-->
                    <div data-role="content">
                        <div data-role="popup" id="statusPopupID" class="ui-content" data-overlay-theme="a">
                            Please Wait...<br/>
                            <img src="{!$Resource.ProgressBar}"/>
                        </div>
                        <apex:form id="idFormSF1">
                            <center>
                                <!--apex:pageBlockButtons -->               

                                     <!--apex:commandButton value="Convert" action="{!convertLead}" status="closer"/-->
                                     <!--apex:commandButton action="{!convertLead}" value="Convert" reRender="redirect('{!accountID.Id}'); "/-->
                                      <!--apex:commandButton value="Convert" action="{!convertLead}" onComplete="redirect('{!accountID.Id}'); retun false;"/-->
                                   <apex:commandButton action="{!convertLead}" value="Convert" onComplete="redirect('{!accountID.Id}'); return false;"/>
                                    <!--apex:actionStatus startText="(Saving...)" stopText="" onStop="redirect();" id="closer"/-->
                                    <!--apex:actionFunction reRender="idPage" action="{!convertLead}" name="CallConvert" id="CallConvert" /-->

                                <!--/apex:pageBlockButtons--> 
                            </center>

                            <label for="OwnerValueID">Record Owner </label> <br/>                                   
                            <apex:inputField value="{!contactId.ownerID}" id="OwnerValueID" styleClass="OutputTextClass"/> <br/>

                            <label for="AccountNameID">Account Name </label> <br/>                                           
                            <apex:inputField value="{!accountId.Name}" id="AccountNameID" styleClass="OutputTextClass"/> <br/>              

                            <label for="OpportunityNameID">Opportunity Name</label> <br/>                                   
                            <apex:inputField value="{!opportunityID.Name}" id="OpportunityNameID"/> <br/>
                        </apex:form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
        </apex:outputPanel> 
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>


17:34:28.142 (1142728575)|USER_DEBUG|[175]|DEBUG|leadConvertResult : Database.LeadConvertResult[getAccountId=0014B000004TFeNQAW;getContactId=0034B000‌​003lE0fQAE;getErrors=();getLeadId=00Q4B000001SWDlUAO;getOpportunityId=0064B000002‌​WxdfQAC;isSuccess=true;] 
17:34:28.178 (1178579313)|USER_DEBUG|[187]|DEBUG|Redirect : System.PageReference[/0014B000004TFeN] 
17:34:28.178 (1178716268)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false 
17:34:28.313 (1313965307)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|leadConvertController invoke(convertLead)
```

Comment: If an error is thrown in your code and you do not display it in a page message component then you may be missing an error which IIRC will cause the oncomplete to no be fired. Take a step back, write a page that has a single button with the JS code. Get that button to work then debug from there. If you get the button working alone you will be more confident / focused in your debugging knowing that it is not the button that is the issue. Oh and is `AccountID.id` an actual thing? Why is the var named AccountiD if it is not an id?

Comment: Thank for reply Brian, actually i am getting the account value in my function. function is being called but i dont knwo why page is not redirecting to account page. see the logs

Comment: 17:34:28.142 (1142728575)|USER_DEBUG|[175]|DEBUG|leadConvertResult : Database.LeadConvertResult[getAccountId=0014B000004TFeNQAW;getContactId=0034B000003lE0fQAE;getErrors=();getLeadId=00Q4B000001SWDlUAO;getOpportunityId=0064B000002WxdfQAC;isSuccess=true;]
17:34:28.178 (1178579313)|USER_DEBUG|[187]|DEBUG|Redirect : System.PageReference[/0014B000004TFeN]
17:34:28.178 (1178716268)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
17:34:28.313 (1313965307)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|leadConvertController invoke(convertLead)

Comment: Your comment is in contradiction to what you say is your questions: `i found out the javascript function which i am trying to call on oncomplete is not even invocking this function` So which is correct?